# Zener Diode - What constitutes "Similar?"

Tags: diode

I have very little experience with ECE in general and I am delving into using an Arduino for some small hobby type projects.

I was following an online guide, and the person who wrote says that I need:
"2 - 1N5227 or similar 3.6V biased zener diodes"

I have read up a bit on Zener Diodes and now understand what they do and what their purpose is. I am not able to tell what he means by similar in this context though. I purchased a Diode Kit that includes 4 types of Zener Diodes. They all have different part numbers and voltages.

The 4 I have are:
1N751 5.1V
1N4733 5.1V
1N4735 6.2V
1N4742 12V

Would any of those be usable in this context or should I order the specific model he states?

The guide being referenced is this, if it is helpful: http://www.instructables.com/id/RC-Transmitter-to-USB-Gamepad-Using-Arduino/

I really appreciate the time and assistance with this, this is a fun area to learn in!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about this being in the wrong section, didn't mean for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In electronics and other engineering areas, similar refers to the property that stands out (in this case the voltage), in your case refers to looking for another zener diode whose voltage is similar to the example. As I see none of those diodes replaces the example.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'll order/pickup some that fit the needed specs then.

Answer (score 0):

Zener diodes has two parameters you need to match in the selection of a replacement (independently the manufacturer):
The Zener voltage (Vz) and the diode power.
For your application you will need a Zener diode of 3.6 V, and usually with 1/4 W to 1/2 W (depending the application power you will need) it will be enough.
You need also to calculate the limiting resistor for the Zener diode.
I recommend you to read the book of Albert Paul Malvino or similar to better understand.
Regards.